# Which is the more efficient/proper method: using ng-repeat to display all, or query in smaller groups first?

Tags: angularjs

I hope this question isn't too *opinionated* as I have seen so many of those type questions closed. I am not looking for preferences or opinions: I just have little understanding on how the code choice plays a role in loading times, server overhead and other terms of that nature.

So I have a scenario that I would like to share with a couple of different routes I could take. I would like to know which way would be more efficient as far as workload, overload, load time, etc goes. I don't need someone to go into deep details on any of those: just simply, which is the best solution?

My scenario is this:

I have a JSON object example that would be retrieved from a PHP page into my AngularJS application:

```
{"links":[
  {
    "Section":"1",
    "Title":"Go to abc.html",
    "URL":"abc.html",
    "GoTo":""
  },{
    "Section":"2",
    "Title":"Go to def.html",
    "URL":"def.html",
    "GoTo":""
  },{
    "Section":"1",
    "Title":"Go to ghi.html",
    "URL":"",
    "GoTo":"2"
]};
```

**SOLUTION 1**

I use an `ng-repeat` to display these, using `ng-if` to decide which link gets displayed. For example, when the page loads, we have `$scope.currentSection = 1`. Then the following in the HTML.

```
<li ng-repeat="x in links" ng-if="x.Section==currentSection">
     <a href="{{x.URL}}" ng-click="changeSection(x.GoTo)" >{{x.Title}}</a>
</li>
```

So this would display any link in "Section 1", in this case, the first and third item in my JSON object. Then, when the user clicks a link that changes the view, `changeSection` simply changes the value of `currentSection`, and voila, the view changes.

This solution is perfect: slick and simple (I just learned how to use `ng-if` so I am personally amazed).

However, now lets say there's 100 items or more in the object. From what I've read, `ng-if` at least keeps all the unused items in the `ng-repeat` out of the DOM which is good, but is it still being bogged down having to go through each item looking for "Section 1"?

Nonetheless, this seems like the more "Angular way" to do it than my next solution.

**SOLUTION 2**

I could `query` just one section at a time. Then do an `ng-repeat` on that. And the function, to change the view, would call a `PHP` file that returns the new query that contains all links in the new section, changing the view probably pretty similarly. I would store the results of this query too, that way if it is needed again, it doesn't need to be retrieved from the server again: since it would be possible to go back to sections.

---

So, we have **1** solution that queries once on the server and the `ng-repeat` uses *all* items to display, only showing the items based on the given `ng-if`. Or solution **2** that queries as the user navigates, communicating to the server more than once, but not infinite amount of times. Plus this is on the assumption we can have 100s of items in the JSON object.

Personally, I would love to be told I can go with the `ng-repeat` method without causing huge overload problems down the road.

Comment: The first one seems good to me, but not with ng-if I would use a filter on the ng-repeat instead. Since i'm not really into performance this is just some guesses.

Comment: @Okazari I will look into filters, I have used them for simple things, but wouldn't have thought to use it for this. I would have to guess though that it would have the same performance though, since it would still need to go through every item to find according to the filter. That is my guess as well. Thank you for the input!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe pagination is better than *get all* approach.

What you can do is implement *caching* in order to avoid further requests to the server during some pre-defined time.

When you use the *get all* approach you should be sure that there's a high change that users will access all data from the UI layer. If not, getting all data is a complete overkill and it increases network traffic.

Also, if each view has a lot of links, I would implement pagination there too. The page size may vary depending on your own requirements.

Comment: I know little about caching, I've tried to read up on it just in general but the documentation is quite confusing for me. But I think something just clicked, it is sort of like cookies then? So, if one user accesses this view or content or whatever, it gets cached because the odds of another user accessing the same view are probably high? If it is a common view. This is for a *intranet* sort of feel website where there's limited amount of users interacting with it at a time, so I don't think traffic would be a huge issue. But, for my own knowledge, that would be interesting to try to implement

Comment: @Christine268 Well, caching can occur on the client-side or server-side ,or even both sides. I was thinking about using DOM local storage or something like that where you can serialize results as JSON and store them there. You can add an expiration date to the stored JSON so if you try to get it after the expiration date, you'll perform an actual request to the server again

Comment: @Christine268 Even in an intranet site, caching can make an turn any app into a blazing fast one. You never know if the intranet is accessed from internet and the user has a slow connection or even your server is busy... If you use basic caching and you avoid server roundtrips, your app will always perform rightly

Comment: You're right. Caching is one of those things that can increase performance no matter what. I will definitely look into it and how I can implement it into my project. Thank you for the information!

Comment: @Christine268 No ptoblem ;)